# Automating database restoration of SQL Server transaction log files on standby mode

Tags: restore, automation

I am wondering if I get help from this house on the following issue. 
I have a standby database that should be restored with the set of transaction log files I get from the vendor's(eClincalWorks) sftp site daily.

The automation I am looking for is to do the following tasks:

1- Download the daily transaction files from the vender's sftp site and save to the local drive. 
Note: the files in the sftp server are in a zip folder named as db_xxxx_today'sDate contains the daily transaction log files that are backed-up every 30 min at the production server.

2. Extracting the zipped folder into a different folder in the local drive
3. Scheduling restoration of the extracted-log files into the SQL database in the correct LSN order and in standby mode.

Please let me know if I need to explain more to my question and thanks in advance for any of your help on this matter!

Lilly.

Comment: @lilly Were you able to figure this out? I am stuck in the exact same step with eclinicalworks. Please let me know what steps you took to make it work if you did.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the first time your client does full backup, you will not be able to restore log files before full backup restore, so that step should be implemented in your automation.